# Excel table losing color in over half of the highlighted cells when exported from ArcMap 10.4 to PDF

Tags: arcgis-desktop, table, pdf, arcgis-10.4

I'm trying to add a table to from Excel into layout view. Bringing it into Arcmap it holds the color in all the highlighted cells and looks perfect. There are about 85 highlighted boxes (out of 740) to show exceedence levels of pollutants. When I export map to PDF the table loses color in about 50 of the 85 highlighted cells. I've brought it in as a JPEG but the quality is poor. I tried to insert an object and create a table but the table looks nothing like it should. It comes out very compact and cannot be read. Anyone have some tips?

Table in Arcmap
[image]

Table exported to PDF
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Adobe illustrator, you could export the map to .pdf, without the table, and then copy and paste the table from ArcMap into the .pdf separately, in Illustrator.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I wanted to put my 2c in as I have had this issue before.

My solutions are as follows:

1. Try changing the DPI of your export. I do not know why, but
   increasing or decreasing the DPI by 1 has helped me.
2. If 1 doesnt work, try changing the output file type. Try *.PNG.
3. If 1 and 2 do
       not work, this step always works. Try "printing" the map using PDF
       software such as PDFCreator. PDFCreator allows you to set the file
       type when saving the print.

   So the steps are: Print, select PDFCreator as your printer, choose where you have to save it and then choose your file name and type. These steps work for me 99% of the time.

Good luck.